# add hard coded header to array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to add an additional header to an array of objects that contain the headers to my table.

My question is, how would I add a header, manually to the same object property 'name'?

I tried to initialize the array before push, but that does not give me the first element.

Example:

```
vm.headers = ["Products"];

angular.forEach(vm.metadata, function (value, key) {                             
    //headers
    vm.headers.push({
        name: value.DataFieldTitle,                        
        });              
});
```

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I was initializing the array incorrectly. I got it to work like:

```
vm.headers = [{Name: "Products"}];
```

And the rest of the code stay the same.

Comment: What do you mean about ```header```? is a property?

Comment: yes, a new header would be a new name

Comment: Is this resolved then?

Comment: Yes. Would you recommend to delete the question? Can I chose my own answer as solution? Thanks.

Comment: You could add your own answer and mark it as accepted (but read first this info http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to look closer to what I was doing, and the simplest way I thought this could be done is by just initializing the array with the value I wanted to have at first position, and then just append the database values.

So the way my solution looks:

```
vm.headers = [{name: "Products"}];

angular.forEach(vm.metadata, function (value, key) {                             
    //headers
    vm.headers.push({
        name: value.DataFieldTitle,                        
        });              
});
```

Thank you.